# Переписал код из учебника, но он работает не так, как должен по мнению автора (он должен воспроизводить звуки)

Tags: java, объекты, аудио, библиотека

Объясните, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы он работал

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

    public class MiniMiniMusicApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
            if (args.length<2){
                System.out.println("Не забудьте аргументы для инструмента и ноты");
            }
            else {
                int insrument = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                int note = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
                mini.play(insrument,note);
            }

        }
        public void play(int instrument, int note){
            try {
                Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
                player.open();
                Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
                Track track  = seq.createTrack();

                MidiEvent event = null;

                ShortMessage first = new ShortMessage();
                first.setMessage(192,1,instrument,0);
                MidiEvent changeInstrument = new MidiEvent(first,1);
                track.add(changeInstrument);

                ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
                a.setMessage(144,1,note,100);
                MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a,16);
                track.add(noteOn);

                ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
                b.setMessage(128,1,note,100);
                MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b,16);
                track.add(noteOff);

                player.setSequence(seq);
                player.start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вот как это было в книге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что не работает-то? конкретнее давайте, как ошибка на какой строчке и т.д.

Comment: @tCode, ошибки нет, но программа выполняет условие, находящиеся после if, по логике так и должно быть, но как сделать так, чтобы программа воспроизводила звук (как и задумывалось автором учебника)

Comment: у меня воспроизводит пару звуков для 102 30 и 40 70.